# Is it possible to use the variable from an optional binding within the same conditional statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement, optional-binding

```
if let popupButton = result?.control as? NSPopUpButto {
    if popupButton.numberOfItems <= 1 {
        // blahblah
    }
}
```

I want to avoid the double nested if.

```
if let popupButton = result?.control as? NSPopUpButton && popupButton.numberOfItems <= 1 {}
```

but I get the `unresolved identifier` compiler error if I do that.

Is there any way to make this condition on one line?  Or because I'm using an optional binding, am I forced to make a nested `if` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
if let popupButton = result?.control as? NSPopUpButton, popupButton.numberOfItems <= 1 {
    //blahblah
}
```

Comment: yup that did it!  do you happen to know the term for the comma here?  e.g, `&&` is a `conditional AND`

Comment: I don't know if there is a term for it, but I just made a quick look on [Swift documentation on optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) and didn't find a term.

Comment: the `,` is used to form a *multi-clause condition*.  This used to be done with the `where` keyword; if you use `where` instead of the comma, the error message mentions using a `,` to form a multi-clause condition.  So I guess that is Swift's term for it.